# adding label from javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, dom

i am trying to add a label from javascript but im getting error

what i did was:

```
document.getElementById(option).innerHTML="<label onclick='updateInfo('edit','qualification',"+data_id+","+data+")>"+data+"</label>";
```

what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why not use jQuery selectors instead of getElementById?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the error is with the quotes inside the function. You have to escape the quotes.

```
document.getElementById('option').innerHTML="<label  onclick=\"updateInfo('edit','qualification','"+2+"','"+test+"')\">"+data+"</label>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the issues with innerHTML in general, you are:

1. Trying to assign JavaScript with innerHTML
2. Apparently trying to set the innerHTML of an <option> element - which can contain only text (not elements) — either that or you are using confusing variable names.
3. Trying to create a <label> which isn't associated (by means of a for attribute or child elements) with a form control.
4. Getting your quote marks muddled (another problem with using string concatination and innerHTML)

Answer (score 0):

The quotes are wrong. you've used single-quotes to quote the onclick value and it's contents.

```
onclick='updateInfo('edit','qualification',"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use document.createElement() and document.appendChild() to avoid the escaping. It also makes the code more readable.

```
        var option = document.getElementById("option_id");
        var label = document.createElement("label");
        label.onclick = function() {
            updateInfo('edit','qualificn',"'" + data_id + "'", "'" + data + "'")
        }
        label.innerHTML = data;
        option.appendChild(label);
```